# High CPU temperatures on Ubuntu 19.04 despite low usage

Tags: gnome, cpu, temperature

After years of not using Ubuntu, I finally decided to reinstall it after my copy of Windows went haywire following an update and I decided I'd had enough.

However, as soon as I installed Ubuntu I started noticing that my laptop gets quite hot fast and when checking the sensors the temperatures normally hover between 65-70C for all elements of the laptop. This is technically fine and it's not overheating per se, but it does get hot to the touch and the fan can sometimes kick off and get pretty loud.

And this is all happening with me using relatively few programs, just a few tabs of Chrome and Spotify for the most part. This wouldn't have been an issue on Windows, CPU temperatures on Windows only reached around 70C if I was doing something more resource heavy, normally hovering between 50-60C.

And yet, on both System Monitor and htop I'm not seeing processes using that much CPU. With the only exceptions being Spotify or Gnome Shell flaring up to 30-50% CPU usage at times, but only for a split second. I was considering installing KDE instead of Gnome Shell in any case, so perhaps that would help, but I haven't done so yet.

I've already scoured the web and this website for all kinds of solutions, but none of them have really had a big impact in helping reduce temperatures, which is why I'm posting this as a standalone question.

My laptop is an [Asus UX51VZ](https://www.asus.com/us/supportonly/UX51VZ), with the following specs:

- Intel Core i7-3612QM
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M (I've already installed
  bumblebee and turned off the GPU, it reduced temperatures a
  bit, but not a whole lot; figured I'd throw it here under specs 
  regardless though)
- 8GB RAM
- 256 GB SSD

Comment: Not a fix, but until someone can help you, you can try dimming your screen as much as is comfortable for you to reduce temp.  Typing top in terminal will tell you if anything is using a lot of your cpu.  Sometimes a background program gets wacky.

Comment: Forget about top, forgot to read well.

Comment: You know if bios was updated, verison 207 has something to do with thermal.

Comment: instead of installing over your whole system, you might want to try kubuntu on the live USB.  It won't be a perfect control experiment but it would be better than starting over to realize there is the same problem on another DE

Comment: @Nmath Good call. Should've thought of that myself.

Comment: @crip659 Reducing the screen brightness seems to not have any impact. :( And my BIOS is version 203, apparently. Should it be updated?

Comment: It probably won't hurt and maybe it will help.  You will probably need to install a working copy of Windows on a separate partition to make it easy.  Can download from microsoft a copy and install.  Check on how to do bios update for Asus.  For acer which I just did for my first time, it was easy just click on the downloaded bios update and it took care of everything.  Be sure you know what you are doing though, read everything you can about doing it, because a mistake can brick your computer.